# Problem with sed on a array containing strings containing spaces

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, string, array

I have a array looking like this:

```
array=("(1 2 3) (123)" "2 31 (231)" "4 5 1 (451)" "(te)xt (1234)")
```

This array is a example. It does not look like this but its structure is the same *(the strings have the same structure)*.
If I want to use the single strings in a `select` loop I can do it like this:

```
select string in "${array[@]}"
do
   # do something
done
```

But the string in the parentheses is not for display. So I used sed to remove them:

```
echo "${array[@]}" | sed -r 's/ \([0-9]+\)$//g'
```

This did not work. Only the last parentheses were removed and the strings have been merged together. But how can I achieve the desired result which would be the same as the following example:

```
array2=("(1 2 3)" "2 31" "4 5 1" "(te)xt")

select string in "${array2[@]}"
do
   # do something
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays have no meaning to `sed`. Once your `bash` array is passed through `sed`, becomes plain text.

Use `bash` to remove the parenthesis (supposing the part to remove is always at the end of the strings):

```
array2=("${array[@]%(*}")
```

(In you `bash` manual check the section about parameter expansion for more.)

Comment: This very nice. But if the first part of the string is also in parentheses then the entire string gets emptied.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!